# Is there a way to dynamically access all variables of a given type?

Tags: c, typedef

I'd like to know if there is a way to access every variable of type `INT` so that I may perform a function on all of them.

In the example below, incrementing n number of integers.

Rudimentarily, my code would look something like this:

```
typedef int INT;

main()
{
    INT a = 1;
    INT b = 2;
    INT c = 3;
    
    // increment all variables of type INT by 1
    
    printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
}
```

The expected result would output `2 3 4`.

Perhaps there is a way to use malloc or calloc for this?
Maybe I'm doing this entirely wrong and if so, please call me out on it.

How could I do the same with structs, if possible?

Comment: How are you going to *print* all of them?  What are you trying to use this technique to accomplish?

Comment: It's not really possible, but it seems to me that if these three are logically tied (which is why you want to do group operations on them), it would be best for them to be in an array, such as `int numbers[] = {1,2,3}`. And then you could simply operate on the array.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you are trying to do. This is clearly an XY-problem.

Comment: This is a little like saying, "I want to get everyone in California named Steve together for a fantastic Steve reunion."  Theoretically you could probably find a way to do it, but it would be a tremendous amount of work, and most people would say, it's not interesting or important enough to do all that work, so in practice, it's basically impossible.

Comment: <O/T> please discard your `typedef`, `int` is just fine.

Comment: @malkaroee That works fine for a single datatype, and I could just dynamically allocate the array size in that case, but it all starts to fall apart if I define a struct (Which was my original plan). AFAK you can't create struct arrays. Could there be an easier way to do this or should I just give up on it?

Comment: @CeddyD of course you create arrays of structs. You should tell us which actual problem you are trying to solve. Creating an array of structs and then iterating the array and applying a function to each element of an array is the way to go. This is a very common practice.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I tried...

`typedef struct Test
{
int INT; char CHAR
}TEST; 
main()
{
TEST test[2]
test[0].INT = 1;
printf(test[0].INT);
...`

But it just ends execution after a few seconds with a stupidly high return value. Where's my error?
Thank you in advance

Comment: @CeddyD of course your code prints nonsense. `printf(test[0].INT)`  is wrong. Did you read the compiler warnings? It's `printf("%d\n", test[0].INT);`. No offense, but apparently you have no clue of the C language. I suggest you get a good book and start at chapter 1.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are looking for something like this!
Let us first define our struct that contains the three ints

```c
    typedef struct int_arr
    {
        int first_int;
        int second_int;
        int third_int;
    }int_arr;
```

Now we are going to write a function that will simply initialize the struct to the value we want and return a pointer to a newly allocated int_arr;

```c
    int_arr * init_int_arr(int first, int second, int third)
    {
        int_arr * new_arr = malloc(sizeof(int_arr));
        new_arr->first_int = first;
        new_arr->second_int = second;
        new_arr->third_int = third;
        return new_arr;
    }
```

And here is the function we will use to print the contents of the struct

```c
    void print_int_arr(int_arr * arr)
    {
        printf("first: %d, second: %d, thrid: %d \n",arr->first_int,arr->second_int,arr->third_int);
    }
```

You have also mentioned that you potentially do not know the size of the wanted array from the begging. Well the best way to have a dynamic array in C, that looks like the one in python is to use linked lists! To understand them well I suggest you first understand how pointers and addressing works in C, but here is a potential example!

[Firstly what is a linked list?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)

Now let us remember that a linked list with a sentinel is easier to loop through and use in general, so that is the approach we will take!
[Sentinel node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node)

Here is our linked_list struct:

```c
    typedef struct linked_list
    {
        int_arr * arr;
        linked_list * next;
    }linked_list;
```

Now lets write the function that will build the sentinel

```c
    linked_list *linked_list_sentinel_build()
    {
        int_arr *sentinel_arr = init_int_arr(-1, -1, -1);
        linked_list *my_list = malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
        my_list->next = NULL;
        my_list->arr = sentinel_arr;
        return my_list;
    }
```

Let us not forget about a custom free

```c
    void linked_list_free(linked_list* head)
    {
        linked_list* previous;
        while (head)
        {
            previous = head;
            head = head->next;
            free(previous->arr);
            free(previous);
        }
    }
```

And here are the two functions allowing you to add values

```c
    // Inserts a value right after the head
    /*
    
        HEAD -> A -> B -> ..... -> Z
        linked_list_insert_beg(HEAD,C );
        HEAD -> C -> A -> B -> ..... -> Z
    
    */
    void linked_list_insert_beg(linked_list *head, int_arr *arr)
    {
        linked_list *tmp = malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
        tmp->arr = arr;
        tmp->next = head->next;
        head->next = tmp;
    }
    
    // Inserts a value right after the head
    /*
    
        HEAD -> A -> B -> ..... -> Z
        linked_list_insert_end(HEAD, C);
        HEAD -> A -> B -> ..... -> Z -> C
    
    */
    void linked_list_insert_end(linked_list *head, int_arr *arr)
    {
        linked_list *tmp = malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
        for (; head->next != NULL; head = head->next)
        {
            // This loop runs to the last node and quits with head being that last node
            continue;
        }
        tmp->arr = arr;
        tmp->next = head->next;
        head->next = tmp;
    }
```

And to end here is the print for your dynamic array

```c
    //Prints the contents of a linked list 
    void linked_list_print(linked_list* head)
    {
        while(head->next)
        {
            head = head->next;
            print_int_arr(head->arr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nice answer, but you're making a lot of assumptions about what the OP wants.

Comment: Yeah I know! I just though If I could give guide ways to linked lists he will understand many concepts of C